# How to set two decimal places of input fields?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular2 and TypeScript. I have input fields values set in .ts file. When I run my application it displays them as whole numbers and I will like to display them as two decimals for example 8.00 instead of just 8.
Here is part of my .ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.phast.operatingCosts) {
      let defaultCosts: OperatingCosts = {
        fuelCost: 8.00,
        steamCost: 10.00,
        electricityCost: .080
      }
      this.phast.operatingCosts = defaultCosts;
      this.startSavePolling();
    }
  }
```

I'm using ngModel. Here is one input field .html:

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input name="electricityCost" type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="electricityCost" (input)="startSavePolling()"
        [(ngModel)]="phast.operatingCosts.electricityCost">
      <span class="units input-group-addon">$/kWh</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom filter like

```
function decimalValue($filter) {
    return (input, size) => {
        return $filter('number')(input, size)
    };
}
```